# Not able to import proj4 in angular project

Tags: angular, openlayers, proj4js

When I am trying to import proj4 in my angular project I am getting an error

> Error: export 'defs' (imported as 'proj4') was not found in 'proj4' (possible exports: default)

I am importing as

> import * as proj4 from 'proj4';

Though I have installed the proj4 as

> npm install --save @types/proj4

How can I solve this issue? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Just check if you have exported proj4 from where it is defined?

Comment: Installing the types is not the same as installing the module. You need to install both the module **and** the types. The types belong in your `devDependencies`. Use `--save-dev` to install them in that location.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/issues/247, for Typescript:

- the import statement should be `import proj4 from 'proj4';`
- *and* compiler option `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true` must be set in `tsconfig.json`

This solved the issue for me for TypeScript 4.8 and Proj4 2.8.

Answer (score 2):

This import statement `import * as proj4 from 'proj4';` used to work before year 2017 for v2.4 of `proj4`.

To use it for 2.4 and above, import it this way: -

```
import proj4 from 'proj4';
```

Also, you might need to do the following changes to your `TypeScript compiler` i.e. inside `tsconfig.json`: -

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

These changes should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Angular 17 and I just ran the recommended action and it appears to have fixed the issue:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/proj4
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to have both `proj4` and `@types/proj4` installed. Rather silly but if it works it works.

```bash
npm i proj4 --save
npm i @types/proj4 --save
```